# onload main page change iframe url

Tags: url, iframe, onload

on my main page i have this:

```
<a href="http://mypage.com/myurl" target="iframename">click here</a>
```

and it works fine, changing the url in the iframe. 
How can I have this with onload of the main page, without having to click on the link "click here" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in the onload event of your main page body element:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('iframename').src='http://mypage.com/myurl'">
```

**UPDATE:**
based on the code posted in comments, try the following instead:

```
<body onload="document.getElementByName('hellaspanorama_iframe').src='http://hellaspanorama.eu/000.html?startpano=images%2F12'">
```

Comment: thanks @Nelson, but it does not seem to work. I made a simplified examble with it : [link]://tinyurl.com/9q626sx  where i have both  

  <!-----  <body onload="document.getElementById('hellaspanorama_iframe').src='http://hellaspanorama.eu/000.html?startpano=images/12'">
  and  
    <a href="http://hellaspanorama.eu/000.html?startpano=images/11" target="hellaspanorama_iframe">
    <font size="6">click here</font></a><font size="6"> </font>  ---->                                               but the iframe only changes with the click link

Comment: @user1473293 Ok, based on your page I've updated my answer, try it and let me know :-)

Comment: thanks @Nelson again but this does not seem to work either: here it is on a new example: http://tinyurl.com/8kj3xl6       Just a thought:  i have an onload function for the iframe like that allready : onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
could it be interfearing with your body onload?

Comment: You have two <body> tags in your page, it must be only one.

Comment: Also, I see no point in changing the iframe src on load if the iframe already comes with that same src .

Comment: thanks @Nelson, fixed that too (I think)  http://tinyurl.com/8bvj8hf new example still not working

Comment: thanks @Nelson Is not the same scr (they load diferent photos)  but I dont think this is an issue, I made a more simple and clear example with clearly different scr  http://tinyurl.com/8zk5fml  if that helps

Comment: additionally I don't think I ll be able to use the "body onload", since the code I' ll add (in html) will be in a blog in several posts, so that whenever a specific post loads, the equivalent iframe link will load too. I can be more detailed, but I try to keep it as simple as I can.

Comment: javascript worked for it But Only on Chrome and IE 9 - on Firefox does not seem to work :   `<script type="text/javascript">document.iframename.location = "http://mypage.com/mynewurl"; </script>`   
on each post's html loads the equivalent link on the iframe other than the default initial `http://mypage.com/myurl`   
All is left it to make the above script work on all browsers. - Any Ideas?

Comment: Use this: `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementsByName('iframename').location = "http://mypage.com/mynewurl"; </script>`

Comment: thanks @Nelson , can't figure out why, but it does not seem to work in any browser : an example with your last code :  http://tinyurl.com/8w3o424  , an example with my last code not working on firefox  :http://tinyurl.com/9l7zt2n  .  Also if it helps:  http://tinyurl.com/9axhquh  the blog. u can see it working on chrome and ie, if u click on any post title or "read more" to load the post's page, the iframe on top changes accordingly